# Is it safe to pass NSManagedObject(created in main context) from a background thread to the main thread?

Tags: core-data

I am using AFNetworking to parse some data and then save to CoreData, I want to do something like this.

```
let parserContext: NSManagedObjectContext = MTCoreDataManager.sharedManager().newPrivateManagedObjectContext()
let mainContext: NSManagedObjectContext = MTCoreDataManager.sharedManager().managedObjectContext()

override func responseObjectForResponse(response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSErrorPointer) -> AnyObject? {
    var model: NSManagedObject?
    parserContext.performBlockAndWait {
        ....parsing data...
        ....create model and assign value...
        ....save model...
        let objID = model.objectID
        mainContext.performBlockAndWait {
           model = mainContext.objectWithID(objID)
        }
    }
    return model
}

let op = AF.GET(path, parameters: nil, success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation, response: AnyObject) -> Void in
        // main thread
        println(response)
}) { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation, error: NSError) -> Void in
        println(error.description)
}
```

As responseObjectForResponse runs in a background thread, I want to use a background context to parse the data and create the NSManagedObject in that context, and then get back the object in main thread as the final callback will be on the main thread, I don't want to return the NSManagedObjectID, I want to return the NSManagedObject but I don't know if this is safe.

Answer (score 1):

Is it safe? I don't think it is.

Instead you should create a child context in the completion block and do all your Core Data saving within a block.

```
childContext.performBlockAndWait() {
    // parse, insert and save
}
```

Remember that saving will just "push" the changes up to the main context. You will still have to save them to the persistent store. The main context should be aware of any changes automatically (via a `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` or `NSNotificationCenter`).

I have an additional convenience method in my data manager class (or app delegate) to save the data to the persistent store, similar to the plain vanilla `saveContext` method provided by the Apple templates. This should a method that can be called safely from anywhere by also using above block API to save the context.